# Calling and Leaving Voice Messages with .Net?

Tags: c#, .net, email, voice, phone-call

I'm looking for a good a way to call phones and leave voice messages using .Net.  The dialog will need to be constructed at runtime for each phone message.  It would be nice if it could handle if the person picks up or an answering service.

Is this something I can use our Cisco VOIP phones to do? If not, whats better using a service (if available) or putting a modem in a machine?  The # of calls will be very low.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think [Twilio](http://www.twilio.com/) will do what you're after.

It can [read and record voice](http://www.twilio.com/how-twilio-works)